# char passing functions with pointers

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, char, turbo-c++

When I write this program in Turbo C++, it works fine. However, when I write in CodeBlocks, Xcode, I get an error regarding `char`, and I don't know why. I thought I could just declare something like `char* name` to use as a string.

This program is about Multilevel Inheritance. Passing Interest rate and Period to the functions, it will display the output according to the Account type.`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class banktype1{
public:
    char *accountType;
    float interestAmt,depositAmt,period,totalAmt;
public:
    void interestCal(char *x,int y,int z){
        accountType=&x;
        depositAmt=y;
        period=z;
        if(accountType=="A")
           interestAmt=depositAmt*0.5*period;
        else if(accountType=="B")
           interestAmt=depositAmt*0.15*period;
        else if(accountType=="C")
           interestAmt=depositAmt*0.25*period;
    }   
};

class banktype2:public banktype1{
public:
    void displayData(){
        cout<<interestAmt<<"\n"<<depositAmt<<endl;
        cout<<"Total"<<interestAmt+depositAmt;
    }
};
class banktype3:public banktype2{

};
int main(){
    banktype3 b1;
    b1.interestCal("A",1000,12);
    b1.interestCal("B",1000,12);
    b1.interestCal("C",1000,12);
    b1.displayData();
    return 0;
}
```

At the place of calling functions, I'm getting this notification:

> conversion from string literal to char * is deprecated.

and also at the place of if condition I'm getting:

> Result of comparison against a string  literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead)

Comment: This code has a *lot* of errors. It's hard to help you since you didn't ask a question. Do you understand what those error messages mean? If so, what's stopping you from fixing them? If not, you should say so -- otherwise we don't know what help you need.

Comment: Turbo C++ is outdated. Its last release is from 2006. It is inexplicable to me why a lecturer would use it in 2014 to teach C++.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz hi. i was having unclear image about using char and pincers passing in functions parameters. after reading some answers. e.g.: after deleting 'const', and assigning * at the if comparison i got it worked.

Comment: So can you edit your question so that it actually contains your question? The more precise you are in explaining what you are unclear about, the more likely is is that you will get an answer that clarifies the specific things you need.

Comment: @ChristianHackl sadly, having teachers who have not updated their knowledge since they finished the college is pretty common. I'm currently studing CS on the university, and thats what I see every day: Stupid teachers doing stupid things (Using Borland C++, using C++ as Java, i.e. `foo* f = new foo;`, etc).

Comment: @Manu343726 . Yes its true. :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals in C++ have types of constant charater arrrays.

But in any case the function definition

```
void interestCal(char *x,int y,int z){
    accountType=&x;
    depositAmt=y;
    period=z;
    if(accountType=="A"){
    interestAmt=depositAmt*0.5*period;
    }else if(accountType=="B"){
    interestAmt=depositAmt*0.05*period;
    }else if(accountType=="C"){
    interestAmt=depositAmt*0.05*period;
    }
}
```

is wrong.

As the compiler warns the first parameter should have type `const char *` if you pass string literals as arguments to the function.

This statement

```
    accountType=&x;
```

is invalid. Thje right operand `&x` has type `char **` while the left operand has type 
`char *` because accountType is declared as

```
char *accountType;
```

This

```
    if(accountType=="A"){
```

and other if else statements are also invalid. Here you are tryying to compare pointers.

It would be much simpler and more correctly if you defined accountType as

```
char accountType;
```

and the function would look as

```
void interestCal( char x, int y, int z )
{
    accountType = x;
    depositAmt = y;
    period = z;
    if ( accountType == 'A' )
    {
       interestAmt = depositAmt * 0.5 * period;
    }
    else if ( accountType == 'B' )
    {
       interestAmt = depositAmt * 0.05 * period;
    }
    else if( accountType == 'C' )
    {
       interestAmt = depositAmt * 0.05 * period;
    }
}
```

and it would be called from main as

```
b1.interestCal( 'A', 1000, 12 );
b1.interestCal( 'B', 1000, 12 );
b1.interestCal( 'C', 1000, 12 );
```

Also if indeed the three if-else statements have the same compound statement then they could be rewritten as one if statement

```
    if ( accountType == 'A' || accountType == 'B' || accountType == 'C')
    {
       interestAmt = depositAmt * 0.05 * period;
    }
```

Comment: Just a minor point: It would make more sense to declare the function as `interestCal( char accountType, int depositAmt, int period )`.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Ah yes Thanks. its worked. i don't know why then our stupid teacher always use pointer thing. when we passing char in functions

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::string` instead of the old C strings, which are just arrays of characters.

Note that the equality operator just compares the addresses of the arrays in the case of C strings, but its overloaded to do string comparison in the case of `std::string`. (So your elseif code should use `std::string`).

Also note that when using C strings, you should use `const char*`, never `char*`.

The solution is simple (And remember it as a good rule of thumb): **Except in rare cases where  its neccesary, always use C++ features instead of its C equivalents**, in this case just use `std::string`. Its dessigned to make your life easier.

Answer (score -1):

Ah It Worked. after making some changes according to answers. deleting `const` . and changing if(accountType=='A') to if(*accountType=='A')

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class banktype1{
public:
    char *accountType;
    float interestAmt,depositAmt,period,totalAmt;
public:
    void interestCal(char x,int y,int z){
        accountType=&x;
        depositAmt=y;
        period=z;
        if(*accountType=='A'){
            interestAmt=depositAmt*0.5*period;
        }else if(*accountType=='B'){
            interestAmt=depositAmt*0.05*period;
        }else if(*accountType=='C'){
            interestAmt=depositAmt*0.05*period;
        }

    }

};
class banktype2:public banktype1{
public:
    void displayData(){
        cout<<interestAmt<<"\n"<<depositAmt<<endl;
        cout<<"Total"<<interestAmt+depositAmt;
    }
};
class banktype3:public banktype2{

};
int main(){
    banktype3 b1;
    b1.interestCal('A',1000,12);
    b1.interestCal('B',1000,12);
    b1.interestCal('C',1000,12);
    b1.displayData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't do that: You are comparing the first character of the array with a character, **not comparing the strings**. Please read my answer.

Comment: This is hardly an answer. You didn't even explain what made the code work!

Comment: @Manu343726 . i have used String before. but our lecture always do using `char` . why above code is wrong. ?

Comment: Well, you have been advised, (regarding on my comments, I have demostrated that your teacher is stupid). Why is wrong? Because C strings are just plain arrays of chars. Remember that. So if you compare them you are not comparing the strings, you are comparing the pointers. Your workaround (Dereferencing the first element of the array) is just a pretty odd workaround to that behaviour, because you are only comparing the first character.

Comment: @Manu343726 Got the idea. Thanks. i was thinking just using string is bad habit. (because my teacher always use char) :)

Comment: accountype[0] == 'A' if you insist in doing that monstrosity of code. the only scary thing is that you programming in c/c++ and you have no idea about how pointers work. I really suggest reading and reading until you drop dead from pointers. Though Manu343726 is 100 % right by suggesting the "std::string" i think u need to revisit pointers before reaching subject like polymorphism

Comment: @NadimFarhat yes. thats what i thought. now I'm getting idea about pointers and how its working..